# filename uploading in django

Tags: python, django, error-handling, image-uploading

i have this code, the code is running well but the problem is that it did not get the file name when uploading the file. my code is  -

views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
        if 'filename' in request.FILES:
            filename = request.FILES['filename']
        else:
            raise Exception('did not get any name')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_profileform/')
    else:

        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('user_profile.html', {'form': form })

def handle_uploaded_file(f):

    destination = open('media/filename', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks(): 
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

form is :-

```
<form action="/user_profileform/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uform" id="userform">{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="usubmit">
</form>
```

the error is :-

did not get any name

Comment: Do you have a `file` or a `filename`? here `handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])` you use `file`, and further you use `filename`

Comment: Post your form code so that it will be easy to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get filename by this

```
filename = form.clean_data['file'].name
```

clean_data can access after form.is_valid() equals True

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name of the uploaded file just by using

```
filename = request.FILES['filename']
```

`.name` is not required. [Refer docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model) for more information.